# Share class memory over shared_ptr

Tags: c++, inheritance, shared-ptr

I want to share object memory between different objects (e.g. Reader/Writer access same memory pool). It works quit good but I have a problem with sharing one shared_ptr.

```
struct A {
  A() {}

  A(const A &other) {
    i = other.i;
  }

  std::shared_ptr<int> i;
};

struct B : public A {
  B(const A &other) : A(other) {}
};
```

I would like to get the second example to work, but it throws an exception. Because the variable i is not initialized and the shared_ptr does not get copied (he is empty).

```
{ // don´t throw
    A a;
    a.i = std::make_shared<int>(10);

    B b(a);
    *b.i = 11;

    printf("%d\n", *a.i);
}  
{ // throw
    A a;
    B b(a);

    b.i = std::make_shared<int>(10);
    printf("%d\n", *a.i);
}
```

Only B should init variable i.

One solution would be following, but do I really need an other wrapper class?

```
struct A {
  A() : i(std::make_shared<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>>()) {}

  A(const A &other) {
    i = other.i;
  }

  std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>> i;
};

struct B : public A {
  B(const A &other) : A(other) {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  { // throw
    A a;
    B b(a);

    b.i->emplace_back(std::make_shared<int>(10));
    printf("%d\n", *a.i->at(0));
  }
}
```

Another example would be just to use raw pointer but I want to ask you, how it could work with a shared_ptr.

The type int is just an example. It could also be an heavy class without default constructor.

Comment: Umm... You can create multiple pointers to the same object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your first scenario

Your code throws, because:

- when you create `a`, `a.i` is an empty `shared_ptr`
- then you create `b` with a constructor copying `a`. So `b.i` is then an empty `shared_ptr`
- then you assign a shared pointer to a newly created object to `b.i`.  But this doesn't change the `a.i` pointer, which is still empty.
- finally you try to dereference `a.i`.   But as a.i is empty, i.e has a usage count of 0 and no valid pointer, it's undefined behaviour (probably a segfault will happen).

## Improvement of first scenario:

You could easily avoid this pitfall by defining the default constructor of A:

```
    A() : i(std::make_shared<int>(0)) {}
```

`a` and `b` would then point to the same shared object, and you wouldn't experience the segfault.

But this approach doesn't of course prevent that someone reassigns `b.i` to another shared pointer.  That's the problem with the `struct`:  you give the key to the house and it's up to you to clean the mess.

An improved variant could be a completely encapsulated class, where i would be protected and functions or operator give access to i.  I choose a way where I overload assignment form int and converion to int, to allow an intuitive usage, but this is a matter of taste:

```
class A {
public:
    A() : i(std::make_shared<int>(0)) {}
    A(const A &other) { i = other.i; }
    operator int() { return *i; }   // you can use A when you could use an int
    A& operator= (int x) {
        *i = x;
        return *this;
    }
    // todo:  copy assigment:  take the pointer or take the value ? 
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<int> i;
};
struct B : public A {
    B(const A &other) : A(other) {}
    B& operator= (int x) {
        *i = x;
        return *this;
    }
    // todo:  copy assigment:  take the pointer or take the value ? 
};
```

The usage of this class would then be:

```
{ // don´t throw
    A a;
    a = 10;
    B b(a);
    b = 11;
    printf("%d\n", (int)a);
}
{ // don't throw either
    A a;
    B b(a);
    a = 1; 
    cout << a <<endl; 
    cout << b << endl;
    b = 10; 
    printf("%d\n", (int)a);  // to make sure that only the int value is passed
}
```

## Your second scenario

In this scenario, you've changed to use a shared pointer to a vector of shared pointer.

I can see no problem with this code and I've experienced no throwing:  [see online demo](http://ideone.com/ZP2QZU)

## Your other thoughts

You can of course work with raw pointers, provided they've been properly allocated with new.

```
int *pi = new int(1); 
shared_ptr<int> spi(pi);
```

But attention:  once you do this, the shared_ptr has ownership. THis means that the shared_ptr becomes responsible for the destruction of the object.

If you would reuse this raw pointer in another shared_ptr (or worse:  if it was obtained from a shared_ptr), your compiler would'nt complain, but you'd get undefined behaviour at runtime, because when the the second shared_ptr would try to destroy an object that was already destroyed by the first shared_ptr (shared_ptr won't be aware of existance of other shared_ptr if constructed from a raw pointer).